# how to prevent javascript trigger click events queue

Tags: javascript, browser

i am firing a **trigger click event** with an interval of 10 minutes. But the problem is when user window is not active or not visible then browser starts storing each and every 10 mins event in queue instead of firing the event and fires all the queue events at the same time when user comes back on the window.

so how to prevent browser to store JavaScript trigger click event queue? please help.

```
setInterval((e) => {
    if($('#refresh_in_10_min').val() == 1){
        $('#refreshbtn').trigger('click');
    }
                        
}, 600000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
setInterval((e) => {
    if($('#refresh_in_10_min').val() == 1) {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            $('#refreshbtn').trigger('click');
        }
    }
}, 600000);
```